# Why do Ruby's default parameter values not get assigned to nil arguments?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and came across something that confused me a bit.

I set a default parameter value in a method signature.

When calling the method, I passed a `nil` argument to that parameter.

But the default value wasn't assigned; it remained `nil`.

```rb
# method with a default value of 1000 for parameter 'b'
def format_args(a, b=1000)
  "\t #{a.ljust(30,'.')} #{b}"
end

# test hash
dudes = {};
dudes["larry"] = 60
dudes["moe"] = nil

# expecting default parameter value
puts "Without nil check:"
dudes.each do |k,v|    
  puts format_args(k,v)
end

# forcing default parameter value
puts "With nil check:"
dudes.each do |k,v|    
  if v 
    puts format_args(k,v)
  else 
    puts format_args(k)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Without nil check:
     larry......................... 60
     moe........................... 
With nil check:
     larry......................... 60
     moe........................... 1000
```

Is this expected behavior?

What ruby-foo am I missing?

Seems like `nil` isn't the same "no value" that I'm accustomed to thinking of `null` in other languages.

Comment: Which other language would use the default value if you give it `null`?! `null` is a proper value in any language I know that uses `null`, just as `nil` is a proper value in Ruby.

Comment: Passing a value to the function, any value, even `nil` for _no value_, overrides the default.  If you want the default, omit the argument.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right. It's not that other languages treat it differently; it's that my mental models are screwed up and it's taking me a bit to get my head back into the code...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah great, but if you do not have ruby 2, how would you "omit" only the second out of 3 parameters?

Comment: @NiklasB. C# does it like you mention and it makes passing arguments much easier.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The default parameter is used when the *parameter isn't provided*.

If you provide it as `nil`, then it will be `nil`. So yes, this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Ruby's splat operator (`*`) when calling that method:

```
dudes.each do |k,v|    
  puts format_args(k,*v)
end
```

Output:

```
     larry......................... 60
     moe........................... 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, methods always return something. Sometimes, there is nothing to return (query in database turns up empty or something like that). `nil` is for those cases; It means something like 'nothing here', but it *is* a reference to an object. To get the behaviour you want, just pass no parameter.

```
def talk(msg="Hello")
  puts msg
end

talk #=> "Hello"
```

Comment: Or use `nil` as the default argument and do a `msg ||= "Hello"` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try ... `v.is_nil?` in the if statement.